# how to copy by specifying line numbers in vi

Tags: vim, vi

How can I copy by specifying line numbers in vi, e.g. lines 364-757? I tried searching for this but cannot find such a command.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`:364,757y` should work just fine, but it is probably more common to just do something like
`364GV757Gy`, allowing the range to be interactively modified when you realize that you really means line 759 or so.

Answer (score 76):

yank those lines in register:

**`:364,757y`<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

if you want to copy those lines and paste to some certain line, **`t`** is your friend. for example:

**`:364,757t2`<kbd>Enter</kbd>**  will copy those lines to **under 2nd line**.

if you want to copy them to **right under your current line**:

**`:364,757t.`<kbd>Enter</kbd>**

Comment: Great examples, precisely the next thing I wanted to learn :)

Comment: The t command `:t` that Kent mentions is an alias for `:copy` -- documented here:  http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:copy

Comment: Thank you. It's worth to mention that if you want to move instead of copy, change `t` with `m`

Comment: Is it possible to do it with relative numbers of lines?

Comment: @StanislawBaranski yes, `.+3` is 3 lines below the cursor

Comment: @Kent But how about the source range. e.g. :.+10,+5t. doesn't work.

Comment: @StanislawBaranski it works here.  In the example you gave a backwards range. try `.+5, .+10t.`

Comment: I need about a month to do nothing but study `vi` commands. I think it'd be worth the investment.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if my answer is needed

but you can yank one line number by

:123y

Answer (score 7):

You can yank (copy in vim terms) from line 364 to line 757 by typing

```
:364,757y<enter>
```